# How to place custom dialog at clicked place in Android?

Tags: android, dialog

Can anybody tell how to place dialog or popup window at clicked place in Android?

Comment: @ I want to show the popup or dialog above of button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a QuickAction Dialog

[How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Notes:
Create One popuplayout.xml file
and parent LinearLayout name give popup_menu_root
and three button name is popup_menu_button1,popup_menu_button2,popup_menu_button3

create main.xml file and put one button

Create MainActivity.java
    setContentView(R.layout.main.xml);

then button click event this code write
```

### OR

```
And This Code Write in Your Click Event Then Point Position Set X And Y to last Line Of Code.


// get the instance of the LayoutInflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Popup.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                // inflate our view from the corresponding XML file
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_root));
                // create a 100px width and 200px height popup window
                final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 200, 200, false);

                pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 250);
                // set actions to buttons we have in our popup
                Button button1 = (Button) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_button1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View vv) {
                        // close the popup
                        pw.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                Button button2 = (Button) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_button2);
                button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View vv) {
                        Toast.makeText(Popup.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                Button button3 = (Button) layout
                        .findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_button3);
                button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View vv) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                // finally show the popup in the center of the window or any position
                // pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```